# Who is using deepstream in production?

Tags: deepstream.io

Are there companies using this technology in production? I would like to find some benchmarks and use cases. We are considering switching to deepstream with mongo from our current firebase setup. But I want to make sure it can handle and scale well enough to meet our demands.

Additionally, if you are using it, what kinds of tech have you used to load test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look [here](https://stackshare.io/deepstream-io) where it is stated that:

> 4 companies reportedly use deepstream.io in their tech stacks, including all, DelightSoft, GraphicWeave, Adinject

Unfortunately, I can not answer your other questions, but you could contact the companies for further info :)